# PHP compare dates <= and >= doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, date, compare, operators

I am trying to compare two date strings of type d/m/y, but it seems that something with the comparison of that type of dates doesn't work. I thought to use DateTime PHP's function, but at first I want to learn why the script above doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
public function listActiveNews(){

    $today = strtotime(date('d/m/Y'));

    $db = mysql_init();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ph_news WHERE newActive = 1";
    $prq = $db->prepare($sql);
    $prq->execute();


    foreach($prq->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $fetch){

        $dateFrom = strtotime($fetch['newsDateFrom']);
        $dateUntil = strtotime($fetch['newsDateUntil']);

        if ( ($today >= $dateFrom) && ($today <= $dateUntil) ){

            print date('d/m/Y') . " >= " . $fetch['newsDateFrom'] .
                  " && " . date('d/m/Y') . " <= " .
                  $fetch['newsDateUntil'] ."<br>" ;
            print $fetch['Title'];
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this result and I cannot understand why the comparison of these dates returns TRUE in the `if` clause.

Output:

> 28/02/2014 >= 20/03/2014 && 28/02/2014 <= 27/02/2014 
>   Title

Here are the dates values:

```
date('d/m/Y') = 28/02/2014
$newsDateFrom = 20/03/2014
$dateUntil  = 27/02/2014
```

Comment: You have your variables backwards. Switch your `from` and `until`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really... stop abusing the date system. `$today = strtotime(date('d/m/Y'));` is utterly pointless. `$today = time()` is the less convoluted and far more efficient version.

Plus, why are you doing the time filtering in PHP when you could simply do it in MySQL?

```
SELECT *
FROM ph_news
WHERE (newActive = 1) AND (curdate() BETWEEN newsDateFrom AND newsDateUntil)
```

will fetch only the records you actually want. Right now you're fetching pretty much the entire table, and then throwing away most everything except the few records you really did want.

Comment: + 1 . . . "stop abusing the date system", I like that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer first of all. But i have to add that dates 'from' and 'until' are stored in MySQL in this type dd/mm/yyyy. The curdate() returns a date in this format 'YYYY-MM-DD' if its string or YYYYMMDD if its a numeric (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate). So that's why your query doesn't seem to work in my occasion. I have to compare somehow dates with this format. dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: you really should store dates in native formats. Look at how much code you have to add just to handle your non-standard formats, v.s. how easy it becomes once you go native and can do everything in the DB.

Comment: Yeah you are right but what can i do if people here can read easily only the dd/mm/yyyy format ?  The only thing that i can do is to convert date type. Anyway. Thank you.

Comment: That's a display problem. e.g. something you do in client-side code just before you output the dates for human consumption. Internally you should ALWAYS use native types.